# не могу собрать таблицу

Tags: laravel

не могу понять как собрать таблицу подобного вида, [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть две таблицы, связанные внешним ключом (подразделения и сотрудники)
перебираю через @foreach, но получается каша

Comment: При чём тут laravel?

Comment: в Laravel делаю)